# Flutter 3 and firebase OTP : "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later"

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase frequently disrupts my Flutter app users when they sign in or sign up using OTP, displaying the message "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later." This issue occurs even during their first time using the app. Is there a way to resolve this problem or disable this feature from Firebase? Or the problem seems to be related to the phone number country ?

Please note that while it sometimes works normally (rare), this error occurs frequently.
All the test numbers have been working without any issues.

Comment: Have you registered your app using appCheck in firebase or check your firebase plan and usage limit

Comment: Can i disbale appCheck from firebase ? my usage limit and firebase are normal

Answer (score 1):

If you try to log in from 1 device to the same number or with other numbers, Firebase understands it as spam and basically the mobile device login is temporarily restricted.

Sometimes we get spammed on some device with a number. Then we want to log in again from a new mobile device with the same number. If this is the case, our new device is also limited.

I faced this problem and here is the answer I found. If you want to test the auth issue while writing the code, you can use it unlimitedly by adding a Test number.

I should also note that it is impossible to prevent the imposition of restrictions. This is something designed by Firebase to prevent abuse.